# How to get links from webpage - BeautifulSoup/Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to get a list of all the links(href) from this website -

https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=brain+tumor&term=&cntry=&state=&city=&dist=

Here is the code I am using and it is producing a blank list

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
productlinks=[]
url='https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=brain+tumor&term=&cntry=&state=&city=&dist='
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
section=soup.find_all('tr', class_='odd parent')
for link in section:
    productlinks.append(link.a['href'])
print(productlinks)
```

Comment: If you go to the site with javascript disabled, you get "Please enable JavaScript to see the List of Studies Found." The `requests` module does not do javascript which is why you get a blank list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=brain+tumor&term=&cntry=&state=&city=&dist='
ajax_url = 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/' + re.search(r'"url": "(.*?)"', requests.get(url).text).group(1)

payload = {
    'start': 0,
    'length':  10
}

for payload['start'] in range(0, 100, 10):              # <-- increase to number of pages
    data = requests.post(ajax_url, data=payload).json()

    # uncomment this to see all data:
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

    for d in data['data']:
        s = BeautifulSoup(d[3], 'html.parser')
        print( s.a['title'] )
        print( s.a['href'] )
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
...

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Show study NCT00003475: Antineoplaston Therapy in Treating Patients With Primary Malignant Brain Tumors
/ct2/show/NCT00003475?cond=brain+tumor&rank=81
Show study NCT00949026: Assessment of Systemically Administered Torisel Delivery to Brain Tumors by Intratumoral Microdialysis
/ct2/show/NCT00949026?cond=brain+tumor&rank=82
Show study NCT04118426: Cognitive Function After Radiation Therapy for Brain Tumours
/ct2/show/NCT04118426?cond=brain+tumor&rank=83
Show study NCT03033706: Intraoperative Goal Directed Fluid Management in Supratentorial Brain Tumor Craniotomy
/ct2/show/NCT03033706?cond=brain+tumor&rank=84
Show study NCT00996450: Educational Follow-up in a Cohort of Children at the Royal Marsden Hospital (RMH)
/ct2/show/NCT00996450?cond=brain+tumor&rank=85
Show study NCT03373487: Cognitive Rehabilitation in Brain Tumor Patients After Neurosurgery
/ct2/show/NCT03373487?cond=brain+tumor&rank=86
Show study NCT03619694: Role of MR Spectroscopy in Brain Tumors
/ct2/show/NCT03619694?cond=brain+tumor&rank=87
Show study NCT00850278: Assessment of [18F]FLT-PET Imaging for Diagnosis and Prognosis of Brain Tumors
/ct2/show/NCT00850278?cond=brain+tumor&rank=88
Show study NCT02575521: Effect of Propofol-Dexmedetomidine on Cerebral Oxygenation and Metabolism During Brain Tumor Resection
/ct2/show/NCT02575521?cond=brain+tumor&rank=89
Show study NCT03248544: Therapeutic Benefit of Preoperative Supplemental Vitamin D in Patients Undergoing Brain Tumor Surgery
/ct2/show/NCT03248544?cond=brain+tumor&rank=90
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Show study NCT03248544: Therapeutic Benefit of Preoperative Supplemental Vitamin D in Patients Undergoing Brain Tumor Surgery
/ct2/show/NCT03248544?cond=brain+tumor&rank=91
Show study NCT00418899: Gliogene: Brain Tumor Linkage Study
/ct2/show/NCT00418899?cond=brain+tumor&rank=92
Show study NCT03216148: 18F-FET PET in Childhood Brain Tumours
/ct2/show/NCT03216148?cond=brain+tumor&rank=93
Show study NCT00961922: Pediatric Research on Improving Speed, Memory and Attention
/ct2/show/NCT00961922?cond=brain+tumor&rank=94
Show study NCT02006563: Metabolic Tumor Volumes in Radiation Treatment of Primary Brain Tumors
/ct2/show/NCT02006563?cond=brain+tumor&rank=95
Show study NCT03234309: Ferumoxytol in Magnetic Resonance Imaging of Pediatric Patients With Brain Tumors
/ct2/show/NCT03234309?cond=brain+tumor&rank=96
Show study NCT01737671: Methotrexate Infusion Into the Fourth Ventricle in Children With Malignant Fourth Ventricular Brain Tumors: A Pilot Study
/ct2/show/NCT01737671?cond=brain+tumor&rank=97
Show study NCT03649880: Feasibility of FMISO in Brain Tumors
/ct2/show/NCT03649880?cond=brain+tumor&rank=98
Show study NCT03465618: A First in Human Study Using 89Zr-cRGDY Ultrasmall Silica Particle Tracers for Malignant Brain Tumors
/ct2/show/NCT03465618?cond=brain+tumor&rank=99
Show study NCT02389530: Use of Fluorescein Dye for the Removal of Brain Tumors
/ct2/show/NCT02389530?cond=brain+tumor&rank=100
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


...
```

Comment: Hi, why *80  on the last line?

Comment: @VoidS `print('-' * 80)` just prints `-` times 80. The `----...` line you see in the output, it's only for aesthetic purposes, to see where the page starts/ends.

Comment: thanks and one last question- why BeautifulSoup.(d[3] what does 3 signify?

Comment: @VoidS If you uncomment the `print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))` you will see in `data['data']` there's a list, where the 4th element is a HTML code with the `<a>` link. So `BeautifulSoup(d[3], 'html.parser')` will decode this code and extracts the link.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `selenium` instead of `requests` to scrape all the links from the page. Here is the full code to do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

productlinks=[]
url='https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=brain+tumor&term=&cntry=&state=&city=&dist='

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(4)

html = driver.page_source

driver.close()

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

a_tags = soup.find_all('a')

for a in a_tags:
    if a.get('href'):
        productlinks.append(a.get('href'))

print(productlinks)
```

Output:

```
['https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/manage-recs/resources#DataElement', 'https://prsinfo.clinicaltrials.gov/results_definitions.html#DelayResultsType', 'https://www.fda.gov/news-events/public-health-focus/expanded-access', 'https://prsinfo.clinicaltrials.gov/results_definitions.html#DelayResultsType', 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/about-site/history', 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/about-studies/learn#Participating', 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/about-studies/learn#Participating', '#main-content', 'https://www.coronavirus.gov', 'https://www.nih.gov/coronavirus', '/ct2/home', '/ct2/search/index', '/ct2/home', '/ct2/search/advanced', '/ct2/search/browse?brwse=cond_cat', '/ct2/search/map', '/ct2/help/how-find/index', '/ct2/help/how-use-search-results', '/ct2/help/how-find/find-study-results', '/ct2/help/how-read-study', '/ct2/about-studies', '/ct2/about-studies/learn', '/ct2/about-studies/other-sites', '/ct2/about-studies/glossary', '/ct2/manage-recs', '/ct2/manage-recs/submit-study', '/ct2/manage-recs/background', '/ct2/manage-recs/fdaaa', '/ct2/manage-recs/how-apply', '/ct2/manage-recs/how-register', '/ct2/manage-recs/how-edit', '/ct2/manage-recs/how-report', '/ct2/manage-recs/faq', '/ct2/manage-recs/resources', '/ct2/manage-recs/present', '/ct2/resources', '/ct2/resources/pubs', '/ct2/resources/alert', '/ct2/resources/rss', '/ct2/resources/trends', '/ct2/resources/download', '/ct2/about-site', '/ct2/about-site/new', '/ct2/about-site/background', '/ct2/about-site/results', '/ct2/about-site/history', '/ct2/about-site/modernization', '/ct2/about-site/for-media', '/ct2/about-site/link-to', '/ct2/about-site/terms-conditions', '/ct2/about-site/disclaimer', '/ct2/manage-recs/register', '/ct2/search/index', '/ct2/home', '/ct2/search/advanced', '/ct2/search/browse?brwse=cond_cat', '/ct2/search/map', '/ct2/help/how-find/index', '/ct2/help/how-use-search-results', '/ct2/help/how-find/find-study-results', '/ct2/help/how-read-study', '/ct2/about-studies', '/ct2/about-studies/learn', '/ct2/about-studies/other-sites', '/ct2/about-studies/glossary', '/ct2/manage-recs', '/ct2/manage-recs/submit-study', '/ct2/manage-recs/background', '/ct2/manage-recs/fdaaa', '/ct2/manage-recs/how-apply', '/ct2/manage-recs/how-register', '/ct2/manage-recs/how-edit', '/ct2/manage-recs/how-report', '/ct2/manage-recs/faq', '/ct2/manage-recs/resources', '/ct2/manage-recs/present', '/ct2/resources', '/ct2/resources/pubs', '/ct2/resources/alert', '/ct2/resources/rss', '/ct2/resources/trends', '/ct2/resources/download', '/ct2/about-site', '/ct2/about-site/new', '/ct2/about-site/background', '/ct2/about-site/results', '/ct2/about-site/history', '/ct2/about-site/modernization', '/ct2/about-site/for-media', '/ct2/about-site/link-to', '/ct2/about-site/terms-conditions', '/ct2/about-site/disclaimer', '/ct2/manage-recs/register', '/ct2/home', '#', '/ct2/home', '/ct2/results/refine?cond=brain+tumor', '/ct2/results/details?cond=brain+tumor', '/ct2/results/browse?cond=brain+tumor&brwse=cond_alpha_all', '/ct2/results/map?cond=brain+tumor&map=', '/ct2/results/details?cond=brain+tumor', '/ct2/resources/rss', '/ct2/resources/download', '/ct2/resources/download#DownloadAllData', '/ct2/show/NCT03286335?cond=brain+tumor&draw=2&rank=1', '/ct2/show/NCT02740933?cond=brain+tumor&draw=2&rank=2', '/ct2/show/NCT03328858?cond=brain+tumor&draw=2&rank=3', '/ct2/show/NCT02367469?cond=brain+tumor&draw=2&rank=4', '/ct2/show/NCT01627535?cond=brain+tumor&draw=2&rank=5', '/ct2/show/NCT03980431?cond=brain+tumor&draw=2&rank=6', '/ct2/show/NCT02956291?cond=brain+tumor&draw=2&rank=7', '/ct2/show/NCT02824731?cond=brain+tumor&draw=2&rank=8', '/ct2/show/results/NCT02034708?cond=brain+tumor&draw=2&rank=9', '/ct2/show/NCT02034708?cond=brain+tumor&draw=2&rank=9', '/ct2/show/NCT00557375?cond=brain+tumor&draw=2&rank=10', '#wrapper', '/ct2/help/for-patient', '/ct2/help/for-researcher', '/ct2/help/for-manager', '/ct2/home', '/ct2/resources/rss', '/ct2/sitemap', '/ct2/about-site/terms-conditions', '/ct2/about-site/disclaimer', 'https://support.nlm.nih.gov/knowledgebase/category/?id=CAT-01242&category=clinicaltrials.gov&hd_url=https%3A%2F%2Fclinicaltrials.gov%2Fct2%2Fresults%3Fcond%3Dbrain%2Btumor', 'https://www.nlm.nih.gov/copyright.html', 'https://www.nlm.nih.gov/privacy.html', '/ct2/accessibility', 'https://www.nlm.nih.gov/plugins.html', 'https://www.nih.gov/icd/od/foia/index.htm', 'https://www.usa.gov/', 'https://www.nlm.nih.gov/', 'https://www.nih.gov/', 'https://www.hhs.gov/']
```

Comment: I get an error message :(

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\skull\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,

Followed by -
File "C:/Users/skull/Desktop/pythonProject3/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

Couple more lines but not many characters left to comment

Comment: Do you have a chromedriver installed? If no, then install it from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: After downloading it, place it in the same directory as your python script. If you don't place it in the same directory, then you have to specify the full file path while calling ```webdriver.Chrome()```, like this: ```driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\ABC\\DEF\\chromedriver.exe')```